# Webpack not including all required files in build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working on rewritting some part of a js library with `WebAssembly` . The library uses `rollup` to bundle and the output created was  `dist/rebound.js` . My changes add an additional file `rebound.wasm` . I didnt use any `wasm loader` but just the `fetch` api to bring to load wasm ,

```
//rebound.js
fetch('rebound.wasm').then(//instantiate)
```

I use `rollup-copy-plugin` to copy the wasm file to `dist/rebound.wasm`. Everything is fine, the dist folder has both js and wasm file. But when I use it in a test project which uses `webpack` and `import rebound from 'rebound'` the `rebound.js` file is present but the `rebound.wasm` file is not present. The `fetch` api gives a 404 error.

I feel `webpack` may be treeshaking it as there is no explicit import statement. How do I make sure `rebound.wasm` would in the js build?

If you need anymore info please ask.

Comment: Had a similar issue with an image. The solution was adding a relative path. Instead of `foo.jpg` I had to use `./foo.jpg` and it works. Did you try `./rebound.wasm` instead of `rebound.wasm`?

Comment: just tried it. didnt work.

Comment: what are you using to serve the build folder ? If the wasm file is in the folder it should be served unless the server ignores it for some reason. Also the wasm file should be served with `Content-Type=application/wasm`